# Une nuance entre « soutenir » et « maintenir »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

> (○) : N'allez-vous pas **soutenir** qu'il n'y a pas d'honneur à affronter une femme ?
>
> (○) : Il **maintient** qu'il n'était pas là le jour du crime.

Je ne peux pas m'empêcher de me dire que l'on ne peut pas substituer « maintenir » à « soutenir » et inversement dans ces deux phrases. Ou je me fais trop d'idées là-dessus ?

> (×) : N'allez-vous pas **maintenir** qu'il n'y a pas d'honneur à affronter une femme ?
>
> (×) : Il **soutient** qu'il n'était pas là le jour du crime.

Comment: Je dirais qu’on soutient un propos et qu’on maintient une position… Donc les premiers exemples me semblent plus corrects. Sans que les seconds me choquent outre mesure.

Comment: en disant "maintenir", il y a une idée de ne pas changer d'avis. Dans "soutenir", il y a une idée de convaincre les autres personnes (comme quand on soutien une thèse par exemple)

Comment: @Random: J'abonde. Je dirais même que maintenir, c'est soutenir de façon répétée.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Maintenir** is used exclusively to mean that you still claim something you said is true. It is an affirmation **you** made about an event mostly relative to you, like "I wasn't there that day".

**Soutenir** does not necessarily imply you supported the statement before, and is often used with an idea, an ideology. It's more philosophical than factual.

Comment: So "maintenir" is about keeping/not changing your claim previously stated, whereas "soutenir" is about holding a belief/idea? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA yep, pretty much.

Answer (score 2):

**Maintenir** has a lot of meaning but the general idea is "**not moving**", in your case it precisely means not changing your point of view.

**Soutenir** is more difficult, the concept is "**to be with**" or "**to help**", in you first example the idea is "don't you agree about what I said ?".

Your first sentence is a bit peculiar because we don't use it anymore in current language, just in movies presenting old stories.

For your switched sentences, the second one is false, because your not by the side of someone or something. Unless, like said in comments, the two "Il" are two different persons, otherwise I personally don't recommend the usage.

The first one is correct, in the idea "you don't want to change your point of view ?", but still we don't use it that much.

Comment: " Il soutient qu'il n'était pas là le jour du crime" is correct and can be used, but the meaning is a bit different as answered by Teleporting Goat,

Comment: " Il soutient qu'il n'était pas là le jour du crime" I think it is more correct if you mean the first and second "Il" being two different persons. If he speak about himself it's not incorrect but really weird.